# Guarantee the number of ticks in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a X axis that has this kind of data:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Sequential numbers. I want to have a bottom axis with X ticks but want to *always* include the first and the last item—which, in this case is: `1` and `15` respectively.

The problem with `d3.ticks` is that it sometimes doesn't return the last tick. And I can't use `nice: true` because all ticks should be numbers that exist in the data set.

Thoughts?

*EDIT*: The goal is to find an even space between ticks considering that the first and the last tick should be always present.

Comment: So, do you want an even space between values? In your example you have a variable gap. Can you elaborate exactly what you want?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Even space between values and it should ALWAYS contain first and last value

Comment: Again: in your desired output (`[0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15]`) you have a gap as little as 2 and as big as 4. Can you elaborate it better? I already deleted one answer, it's a good idea explaining exactly what is the output you want before users trying to provide you an answer, do you see?

Comment: Updated my question. Wasn't the best example, but again—the goal is to have even space between ticks and making sure that first and last value will be always displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your specific situation you can use `d3.range` to generate the ticks, that you'll pass to your axis' `tickValues` method. For instance:

```js
const scale = d3.scaleLinear([0, 15], [0, 1]);
const numberOfTicks = 7;
const tickStep = (scale.domain()[1] - scale.domain()[0]) / (numberOfTicks - 1);
const myTicks = d3.range(scale.domain()[0], scale.domain()[1] + tickStep, tickStep);

console.log(myTicks)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

However, due to the floating-point precision issues, you may have an unexpected length for your array depending on the combination of domain/number of ticks. For instance, using `[8,15]` as the domain and 7 ticks:

```js
const scale = d3.scaleLinear([8, 15], [0, 1]);
const numberOfTicks = 7;
const tickStep = (scale.domain()[1] - scale.domain()[0]) / (numberOfTicks - 1);
const myTicks = d3.range(scale.domain()[0], scale.domain()[1] + tickStep, tickStep);

console.log(myTicks)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, we have 8 elements in the array, not 7.

For dealing with those cases, you can just pass the number of ticks to `d3.range` and deal with the math using `map`:

```js
const scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([8, 15]);
const numberOfTicks = 7;
const tickStep = (scale.domain()[1] - scale.domain()[0]) / (numberOfTicks - 1);
const myTicks = d3.range(numberOfTicks)
  .map(d => scale.domain()[0] + d * tickStep);

console.log(myTicks);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

#### Integers

The previous examples generate *evenly spaced* ticks. However, I suppose you want integers as values. In that case, pay attention to the fact that **you cannot have** both integers and evenly spaced ticks for all possible combinations of domain and number of ticks.

To get integers, just round the values:

```js
const scale = d3.scaleLinear([0, 15], [0, 1]);
const numberOfTicks = 7;
const tickStep = (scale.domain()[1] - scale.domain()[0]) / (numberOfTicks - 1);
const myTicks = d3.range(scale.domain()[0], scale.domain()[1] + tickStep, tickStep)
  .map(d => Math.round(d))

console.log(myTicks)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

And here the same approach as the third snippet, doing all the math in the `map` and using `[8,15]` as an example:

```js
const scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([8, 15]);
const numberOfTicks = 7;
const tickStep = (scale.domain()[1] - scale.domain()[0]) / (numberOfTicks - 1);
const myTicks = d3.range(numberOfTicks)
  .map(d => Math.round(scale.domain()[0] + d * tickStep));

console.log(myTicks);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing with a time scale?

Comment: @CentaurWarchief yes, it is, you just need to parse the dates inside the `map`.